# saving an updated table value after being updated in the front end when it's not an input value, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm creating a game and in my user table I added a value called 'money' for each user. 'money' has a default value of 100. I passed that value to the front-end so the player can see that value. During game play, that value changes (let's say from 100 to 125). My question is how is that value able to be saved and updated to the user table. In the docs, it's seems like only input values can be updated and this is not an input value. It is just a number that has changed value.

User Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('money')->default(100);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Homecontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('money', 100)->first();
        return view('home')->with('users', $users);
        $users->save();
    }
}
```

Home.blade.php file

```
<div class="col-xs">
    <div class="amountOfMoney">{{$users->money}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi J Spade, welcome to SO. Your question is too broad to answer. It's not that it's incorrect, but what you are looking for requires a minimum understanding of how an MVC (Model View Controller) architecture works. That is how Laravel works, also. You basically need to create routes, controllers and views to update your User model `money` attribute and then `->save()` it to update the database field. If your project is open source feel free to share repo and I may hint you with a pull quest.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have a User model, which should be included in the Laravel installation. If so, you can simply use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) to update properties fairly easily.

For example:

```
//Get user
$user = Users::where('money', '=', 100)->first();

//Update money value
$user->money = 125;
$user->save();
```

If not, you could create your own user model or just update the data with the DB facade:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->where('money', 100)->pluck('id')->first();
DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->update(['money' => 125]);
```